# How to set associations deletedAt fields with soft delete?

Tags: go, go-gorm

How should I delete my associations in with soft delete?

I have the following structs

```
type PrivateGormModel struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id,string"`
    CreatedAt time.Time  `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time  `json:"-"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `gorm:"index" json:"-"`
}

type Relation struct {
    PrivateGormModel
    OwnerID      uint          `json:"ownerID"`
    OwnerType    string        `json:"ownerType"`
    Addresses    []Address     `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"addresses"`
    Contacts     []Contact     `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"contacts"`
    People       []Person      `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"people"`
    BankAccounts []BankAccount `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"bankAccounts"`
}

type Company struct {
    PrivateGormModel
    Name     string   `json:"name"`
    Relation Relation `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"relation"`
}
```

I left out the adress, contact, person and bankaccount struct to keep this post short but they are simple structs with a `OwnerID` and `OwnerType`. And the following handler

```
func DeleteCompany(db *database.Database) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        id, err := IDFromParams(c)

        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.ParameterMissing())
        }

        toDelete := new(model.Company)
        result := db.Preload("Relation.Addresses").
            Preload("Relation.Contacts").
            Preload("Relation.People").
            Preload("Relation.BankAccounts").
            Preload(clause.Associations).
            First(toDelete, id)

        fmt.Printf("\n%v", toDelete)

        result = db.Select("Relation.Addresses").
            Select("Relation.Contacts").
            Select("Relation.People").
            Select("Relation.BankAccounts").
            Select("Relation").
            Debug().
            Delete(toDelete)
        if result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordDeleteError())
        }

        return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordDeleteSuccess())
    }
}
```

Where the print outputs

```
{PrivateGormModel:{ID:5 CreatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.672857 +0100 CET UpdatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.672857 +0100 CET DeletedAt:<nil>} Name:Test Relation:{PrivateGormModel:{ID:5 CreatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.738351 +0100 CET UpdatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.738351 +0100 CET DeletedAt:<nil>} OwnerID:5 OwnerType:companies Addresses:[{PrivateGormModel:{ID:5 CreatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.739322 +0100 CET UpdatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.739322 +0100 CET DeletedAt:<nil>} OwnerID:5 OwnerType:relations Country:AA Zip:1111AB Number:1 Addition: Street:Test State:Test City:Test}] Contacts:[{PrivateGormModel:{ID:5 CreatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.740319 +0100 CET UpdatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.740319 +0100 CET 
DeletedAt:<nil>} OwnerID:5 OwnerType:relations Tel:0612345678 Mail:test@test.com URL:}] People:[] BankAccounts:[{PrivateGormModel:{ID:5 CreatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.740319 +0100 CET UpdatedAt:2021-01-15 11:24:03.740319 +0100 CET DeletedAt:<nil>} OwnerID:5 OwnerType:relations Bank:test BIC:test IBAN:test AccountHolder: Establishment:test}]}}
```

and the debug debugs the following

```
DELETE FROM "relations" WHERE "relations"."owner_type" = 'companies' AND "relations"."owner_id" = 5
DELETE FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = 5
```

So the relation is deleted. But it isn't doing anything for the hasMany relation. I read this

https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select

And tried to do that since the constrains don't seem to do anything, but nothing seems to work and delete the adresses, contacts, people and bank accounts. How am I supposed to soft delete all the relationships of Company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this with the latest version of Gorm, and Select and Delete only works for first-level associations.

So if you did

```golang
db.Select("Relation").Delete(toDelete)
```

You'd see that both Company and Relation get their DeletedAt set to the current timestamp.

To achieve soft-deletion of the second-level relations, you'd need to delete those in a separate call:

```golang
db.Select("Addresses", "Contacts", "People", "BankAccounts").Delete(toDelete.Relation)
// or more compactly
db.Select(clause.Associations).Delete(toDelete.Relation)
```

It may also be worthwhile asking yourself whether soft-deleting just the root of the model tree, and leaving everything else as-is isn't sufficient for your usecase.